# Adding events to array of buttons in scrollview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4

I am creating an application which contains a timeslot screen where users are displayed a list of buttons in half an hour slots. I I have timeslots going from 9 - 6.

I created the buttons by creating a for loop like this

```
    UIButton *csBut = [[UIButton alloc]init];
    csBut = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    csBut.frame = CGRectMake(xPos, yPos, 145, 55);

    [csBut setImage:[imageList objectAtIndex:i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [SV addSubview:csBut];
```

I set up the image of each button using the imageList array I have created. SV is the scrollview I have set up. Each button is added to this scrollview. The buttons are all displaying perfectly. Now the problem I am having is that when I try and set up the buttons to do something, its not responding to  the button clicks. I have been using

```
[csBut addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

and the method I have created should simply display an alert (just temp till I get this working properly)

```
-(IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender{
//ConfirmBut.hidden = NO;

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning" message:@"Testing"
                                               delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles: nil];
[alert show];
```

}

However, when I click the button, nothing happens. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Can you post the whole code where you are creating your buttons?

Comment: Consider using a `UITableView` and triggering the behavior you want by detecting when the user selects a row. It will look much nicer, and it's behavior will be more flexible and easier to manage than the custom solution you're trying to implement.

Comment: Only problem I have with table view is that the background is pure white, and I have a background theme throughout my entire application which is shown. I am not sure how exactly to set the background to a tableview yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIScrollView Does not directly Respond to Touch Events, So You just need to allocate a UIView in your for loop and add your button to that view like below. so the problem may be resolved. Keep Coding..

```
UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xPos, yPos, 145, 55);]
    UIButton *csBut = [[UIButton alloc]init];
        csBut = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        csBut.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 145, 55);

        [csBut setImage:[imageList objectAtIndex:i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [myView addSubview:csBut];
[SV  addSubview:myView]
```

Answer (score 1):

UIButton is a subclass of UIView, so it has tag too. For example, I made a custom actionSheet, it contains a list of UIButtons. When I push down a UIButton, I need to know which button I pressed. So, I assign the row information to tag.

```
 NSArray *buttonListArray = ....; ///< UIButton array, a button per row.
 for (int tag_id = 0; tag_id < [buttonListArray count]; ++tag_id) {
UIButton * csBut = [buttonListArray objectAtIndex:tag_id];
csBut.tag = (100 + tag_id);
}
```

When I touch the button, I can get the row information by

```
- (void)buttonTouched:(id)sender {
   UIButton * csBut = (UIButton *)sender;
   NSInteger tag_id = (csBut.tag - 100);
}
```

tagging  is must if we handle the array of button. I think your last button maybe response for button click rest of them are over ride by one another

Comment: Thanks a lot for this one, this one really helped. Took me a bit of messing around with it to understand how it works, but this is exactly what I need in order to create the next function I require. Cheers!!!!